# Android Changing xml

Tags: android, xml

Hello I want to change text in my textView , but dont know how. 
I tryed to change it like this

1. ```
   TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
   textView3.append("hi");
   ```

   But this textView is in another xml-file.

   the compiler outputs
2. ```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nividimka.shopapplication/com.example.nividimka.shopapplication.ShopActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.example.nividimka.shopapplication.ShopActivity.onCreate(ShopActivity.java:62)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question is not clear, but i believe you are trying to update the text of a **TextView** which is on another activity/previous. Then you may declare the **TextView** as **public static** in the class where the actual layout file(containing textview) inflated.

```
Class PreviousActivity extends Activity{
     public static TextView textView3 ;


// inside onCreate(), after setContentView()
//initialize to avoid null-pointer.
textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
}
```

then you can try from otherActivity.

```
PreviousActivity.textView3 .append("new txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no textview with id `R.id.textView3`, so `findViewById` returns null. Are you sure you've called setContentView, or the layout is attached to your activity?